# Repeat Textbox on every page in rdlc report repeatwith property

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, rdlc

I do have text box (txtstatic )where im showing static text , below that there is a table (tablix 2) which will show all the pages with records .

My requirement is, I have to show the textbox ( txtstatic) every page above the table(tablix2)

So I have made textbox property repeatwith "tablix2" . but still the textbox is showing only one page and its not repeated.

Am i missing anything here?

Answer (score 3):

You have two options here, because this property is kinda bugged.

First one you can put the textbox in the report header (**Insert > Header & Footer > Add Header**), so it will repeat on every page.

The second option is to insert a row (above) in your tablix, merge this row and add your text. Afterwards you have to enable that your tablix repeats the column header on every page. For this you need to click on your tablix, then go to the bottom right by **Column Groups**, select the drop down and chose **Advanced Mode** which gives you the automatically created static members from the row headers. Now select the relevant **static group** under **Row Groups** and chose in the property pane **RepeatOnNewPage = True** and **KeepWithGroup = After**. The header rows will now repeat on every page

Comment: Nearly three years later and this is still gold! Thank you.